# C# How to change row color in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/c-sharp-how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

I would like to change the color of a particular row in my datagridview. The row should be changed to red when the value of columncell 7 is less than the value in columncell 10. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

EB