# how to change row color on RowsAdded event in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

I have a dataGridview which refreshes after every 1 minute and new rows are added in it (dataGridView). Now I want to change the forecolor of those newly added rows based on some condition. Please tell me how do I achieve it?

Regards
Zuhaib

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/c-sharp-how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview?

Comment: another example of changing color on events [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036580/wpf-change-datagrid-cell-row-background-color-dynamically-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

for this you can play from DataGridView's _RowLeave() Event...
Also for NewRow(), you can check wherther that cell value is blank or Not Exist() then it can applied to dataGridView Cell Style.. like the below manner....

```
Form_Load()
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle AStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    AStyle.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;

    blah...blah...blah..
}

private void MyDataGrid1_RowLeave(Object Sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    for (int I1 = 0; I1 < dataGrid1.Columns.Count - 1; I1++)
        {
            if (I1 == 3 || I1 == 5)
                {
                    dataGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells[I1].Style = AStyle;   
                }

    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can change cell font in RowsAdded event. I do in Visual Basic so you can translate it into c#, here the code:

```
    Private Sub DatagridView_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DatagridView.RowsAdded
    With DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If .Item(yourColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value Is "yourValue" Then
            .Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
            .Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkRed
            .Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 8, FontStyle.Strikeout Or FontStyle.Bold)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I hope this works for you