# How to change row color in datagridview after checkbox is selected

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to change the color of a particular row in my datagridview after my row Chckbox is in selected mode:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool isSelect = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value as bool? ?? false;
    if (isSelect)
    {
        // Change row color
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/c-sharp-how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isSelect)
{
    // Change row color
    var row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```