# Change color rows in datagridview when compare date

Tags: c#

I have some trouble with a small C# project. In my database, I have 3 columns:

```
ID(int), NameProducts(nvarchar), DeadLine(nvarchar)
```

The reason why I set the deadline field to nvarchar, is because in my form I made a datetimepicker, which set the property for this control.

Format: custom and custom format: dd-MM-yyyy.

But when I insert or update a record, I always get following message: Cannot convert.

How could I change the color of rows in a datagridview while comparing deadline and the current time.

```
if ( time now < deadline about 3 days ) // change color to Yellow
if ( time now < deadline about 1 days) // change color to orange
if ( time now => deadline ) // change color to RED.
```

Comment: What is the value of your `deadline` exactly? It is a string I think, right? You want to parse it with `dd-MM-yyyy` format?

Comment: i set type string.because when i selected data from datagridview to textbox.it'll show dd-MM-yyyy.if i set field deadline :"datetime" then database 'll show yyyy-dd-mm.And if insert,update,select will show error.So i want to ask: how can compare to date between deadline(string) and time now(datetime).thks

Comment: For storing the `deadline`, you should really use a datetime type in the database (you didn't mention which database you're using). You can get the value of the datetimepicker as a DateTime, irrespective of its display format, by getting `DateTimePicker1.Value()`. For changing the colour of rows in a DataGridView, please see [C# How to change row color in datagridview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/c-sharp-how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview).

Comment: thk Andrew Morton.i'll try.But if not run i'll paste code here and fix for me.ok!

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using switch case :
like this

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int quantity = int.Parse(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblId")).Text);

            switch (quantity)
            {
                case 1:
                    e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");

                    break;
                case 2:
                    e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00FFFF");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0000FF");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFA500");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF00");
                    break;            

            }
        }
```

Comment: i think u use event : datagridview_Rowdatabound.correct?i use winform.must i use what events?