# Fill color text in gridview character?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

Ask fill color Text in a Grid View, Grid View data is loaded, the highlighters in grid view under one condition such as larger amounts 1.000 or character as mas ... see attached image file

[IMAGE](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img538/5173/kG8gFV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you want to change the color of certain rows/columns in the dataGridView based on some conditions.

Please see following link:  [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

EDIT: You can change the condition to whatever you like, if the values in the cells exceed certain amount, if the characters length exceed a certain length etc.

Comment: In much the same, but not colored in column 2 columns that fill many row if the terms and conditions given, you see the attached file illustration photo
[IMG]http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img673/7277/mdviQ0.jpg[/IMG]
[IMG]http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img673/6720/FH72ZX.png[/IMG]

Comment: I do not understand, could you please give me more details, and I will try to help you.

Comment: I want to color text in the image file as an attachment, ie black font color, background color of the font color yellow, you see attach file http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img538/2010/8SG2Vq.jpg