# Color Row Conditionally

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This is my WPF code when creating the DataGrid:

```
       <DataGrid x:Name="DGruta11" Height="365" Width="836" Canvas.Left="19" 
                     Canvas.Top="115" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                     HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFD8D8D8"
                     VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFD8D8D8"
                     IsReadOnly="True" >

       </DataGrid>
```

I'm filling this grid up with a datatable created in C#.

I'm getting 19 rows in total and I will always receive this amount. The row 0, 1, 2 should be gray and bold letters.

Rows 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 should be Light Gray.

Rows 10, 11, 12 should be White.

Rows 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 should be Gray again.

A part of that, but using the same datagrid if the cell is number then I want that number to be this format 0.00 ("9.00" , "1, 000.00" ,"0.05" )

Also starting from column 2nd and above all information should be align to right.

I hope you can help me with this out. I appreciate and I thank everybody for aid.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourDataToBind}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding YourDataToBind.ValueAsCondition, Converter={StaticResource YourValueToColorConverter}}"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter> 
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="ColumHeader" Binding="{Binding ValueInColum}" />
                    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of your rows in c#. There's a very good example here on how to do it [How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

Basically you would loop in all of your rows and with conditional statements, determine which color should be applied to this row.

Something like this:

```
int rowCount = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGruta11.Rows) 
{
    rowCount += 1;
    if (rowCount > 2 && rowCount < 10) 
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray; 
    }
}
```