# Get datagridview row from datatable row

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have found that one can get the bound datatable row for a datagridview row, however, I am seeking to do the opposite. I have the following working code that sorts the datatable rows into an array sorted by a date field. I am then performing some logic to fill a value based on how much quantity is available. When the quantity available is less than the quantity required, I want to color the datagrid row to let the user know of the situation. How can I refer to the correct datagridview row at this point?

Update For Clarity : This is a winform using a datagridview. The code shown is on a "Match All" button. Its purpose is to match a Qty to Transfer value from a Qty Required cell up to an available quantity for the row's Item.

```
Dictionary<string, float> availableQtys = new Dictionary<string, float>();

DataView view = new DataView(dtStaged);
DataTable distinctItems = view.ToTable(true, "Item");

for (int i = 0; i < distinctItems.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    availableQtys[distinctItems.Rows[i].Field<string>(0)] = 
          Controller.Instance.GetAvailableQty(distinctItems.Rows[i].Field<string>(0), ddl_SourceLocation.SelectedValue.ToString());
}

DataRow[] rowList = dtStaged.Select("", "Req Ship ASC");

foreach (DataRow row in rowList)
{
    if (ddl_SourceLocation.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() == row["Dest Site"].ToString().Trim())
    continue;

    if (availableQtys[row["Item"].ToString()] < Convert.ToSingle(row["Qty Required"]))
    {
        row["Qty to Transfer"] = availableQtys[row["Item"].ToString()];
        availableQtys[row["Item"].ToString()] = 0.0f;
        warnUser = true;

        // HERE I want to set the color of the matching data grid row
    }

    // some other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you use WinForms. And you probably use DataGridView to display your data.

The best solution for you is to create custom cell template.

For instance you can inherit DataGridViewTextBoxCell, and override OnPaint method.
There are 'rowIndex', and 'value' among the parameters of OnPaint method.

This way your template will be able to consider data bound item and paint the cell accordingly.

Another solution is to manually update rows color every time your data changed.
Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview).

Comment: Are you asserting that my exact desire - deriving the associated datagridview row from a datatable row - is not possible?