# change color of every datagridview row containing a certain value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

Is this possible? what i'm currently doing is just looping through each row to change the color, but this is very slow since i'm also running a query and based on the results I change the color. Here's an example

```
Part No | Other Columns
-----------------------
Part A  | 123456
Part B  | 123456
Part C  | 123456
Part A  | 123456
Part A  | 123456
```

My query's where is `Where Part_No = 'Part A'`, with my current method I would just be running the same query 3 times. What I want to do is get the distinct Values on the first column, check those in the query and change the color of the rows containing that value.

Comment: Is the dgv bound to something like a DataTable?  if the WHERE clause is `Part_No = 'Part A'` what are Part B and C doing in there?

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry, I guess it wasn't clear.  Yes, the datagridview is bound to a datasource. The where clause I mentioned is for the query when i'm looping through each row.

Answer (score 0):

answered here: [How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

===

*I was just investigating this issue (so I know this question was published almost 3 years ago, but maybe it will help someone... ) but it seems that a better option is to place the code inside the RowPrePaint event so that you don't have to traverse every row, only those that get painted (so it will perform much better on large amount of data:
Attach to the event*

```
this.dataGridView1.RowPrePaint 
    += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventHandler(
        this.dataGridView1_RowPrePaint);
The event code

private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Text) < Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]..Cells[10].Text)) 
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An economical way is to use the `CellFormatting` event.  This will fire when that cell is displayed the first time.  It will only fire for the visible rows so it should be faster.

`Then I loop through the grid view to do something like update the data of all colored rows`

If the data comes from db (the OP mentions a query) you ought to be acting on the data like the datasource.  The DGV is just the user's view of the data.  Rather than acting on rows of a certain color, act on the part number or whatever determines the color.  You could also create a view of the records with this or that part number and act/loop on that to simplify the process.

Since the data can change, you'll want to handle 2 events: `CellFormatting` and `CellValueChanged`

```
Private Sub dgv1_CellFormatting(...) Handles dgv1.CellFormatting
    ' default start up color
    If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
        e.FormattingApplied = ColorMyRow(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
    Else
        e.FormattingApplied = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dgv1_CellValueChanged(...) Handles dgv1.CellValueChanged
    ' if the target cell changes, update
    If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
        ColorMyRow(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub

' DRY
Private Function ColorMyRow(rowIndex As Int32, colIndex As Int32) As Boolean
    Dim bass As Color = Color.PeachPuff
    Dim pike As Color = Color.SeaShell
    Dim salmon As Color = Color.Salmon

    Select Case dgv1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(colIndex).Value.ToString
        Case "Bass"
            dgv1.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = bass
            Return True
        Case "Pike"
            dgv1.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = pike
            Return True
        Case "Salmon"
            dgv1.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = salmon
            Return True
    End Select

    Return False
End Function
```

The color will be updated whether a) the user edits the cell, b) you change a cell value ( `dgv1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = "Mermaid"` ) or c) you change the datasource ( `dtParts.Rows(0)(3) = "Pike"`).

Finally, rather then trying to loop on the blue rows, you can query the `DataSource`, in this case, a `DataTable`:

```
Dim bassRows = dtSample.Select("Fish = 'Bass'")
For Each dr As DataRow In bassRows
    dr("Fish") = "Pike"
Next
```

The color will automagically change.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, haven't gotten around to trying this but since you mentioned this only colors the displayed rows, how will this work if I loop through the datagridview and what I do will depend on the color of the row.

Comment: There is no need to loop thru anything.  Looping thru all rows - many of which are not visible (and may never be)  is what is causing it to be slow. As each row scrolls into view, the event will fire and the back color will be set.  What you do ought not depend on the color, but the same determinant used to set the color.

Comment: What I mean is looping after the colors are set. Let's say I use your method, some displayed rows are now colored. Then I loop through the grid view to do something like update the data of all colored rows, will the rows not visible but are suppose to be colored be updated?

Comment: You didnt mention anything about the data changing; still looping on the dgv rows is suboptimal: if the data comes from a DB, you ought to be acting on the Data (datasource) not the user's view of it.  Edited.