# Change row color based on text in column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to change the color of the row in a datagridviewer based on the text that is in one of the columns. I'm getting the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on the line of the first if statement. I filled in the datagridviewer based on a datasource which the code is also below.

```
 void ChangeDataGridViewColor()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in datagridviewTreatmentPrep.Rows)
        {
            if (Row.Cells["Primary Onc"].Value.ToString() == "JMK")
            {
                Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }

            if (Row.Cells["Primary Onc"].Value.ToString() == "DBF")
            {
                Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            }

            else
            {
                Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }

    }

 void FillDataGridViewTreatmentPrep()
    {
        string constring = "datasource = RadOncViewerDatabase.db";

        string TreatPrepQuery = "SELECT * FROM TreatmentPrep";

        SQLiteConnection connectionstring = new SQLiteConnection(constring);

        connectionstring.Open();

        DataTable dsTreatPrep = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter adapterTreatPrep = new SQLiteDataAdapter(TreatPrepQuery, constring);
        adapterTreatPrep.Fill(dsTreatPrep);

        datagridviewTreatmentPrep.DataSource = dsTreatPrep;                     

        //datagridviewTreatmentPrep.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
        //this.datagridviewTreatmentPrep.DataSource = dsTreatPrep.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Patient_Name");

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `Row.Cells["Primary Onc"].Value` is not null? You know the row exist... but its value may not.

Comment: Yes. The value of the column name is Primary Onc. I think the confusion may lie in the fact that i've filled the datagridviewer with a dataset and I'm not referencing the column properly.

Comment: Step through the code and see what column names are in `dsTreatPrep` if there is not a column called `Primary Onc` then this will explain your error.

Comment: Also since the `DataGridView` is bound to the table, you will need to use something like `Row.DataBoundItem` to get the correct value from the data table.

Comment: probably needs to be called in/after the `DataBindingComplete` event or better in the `RowPrePaint` event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the the [`RowPrePaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint) event, and don't use `.ToString()` on objects that can be null:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    var row = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Primary Onc"].Value);
    //or in VS 2015: string value = row.Cells["Primary Onc"].Value?.ToString();

    if (value == "JMK")
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    else if (value == "DBF")
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    else
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually works! I had to modify it to use the foreach DataGridRowView like what @JohnG suggested.

Comment: @LitteringAnd I hope you are not using loop in the RowPrePaint event because it is called for each displayed row.

Comment: I had to because without it your code throws an error due to index being out of range. The error occurs on the var row line. I think it's because the datagridview is based on a datatable initially and there's nothing there to index. Just a guess.

Comment: @LitteringAnd I think I forgot to exclude the header row. If the updated code doesn't work, you can use a loop in the `DataBindingComplete` event.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code I have tested and it works as expected. Sorry for the delay.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
  DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)Row.DataBoundItem;
  if (drv != null) {
    if (drv.Row["Primary Onc"].ToString() == "JMK") {
      Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else {
      if (drv.Row["Primary Onc"].ToString() == "DBF") {
        Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
      }
      else {
        Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @JohnG. It makes sense to me what you did, but says 'DataRowView does not contain a definition for Cells.'

Comment: I changed the line that was causing problems. I am sorry I am unable to get to my computer at this time.

Comment: @LitteringAnd I was able to test this and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you must use DataGridViewCellStyle class
my solution:

```
     int max = dgv.Rows.Count;
 DataGridViewCellStyle style;
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)

                for (int j = 2; j < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)

                    if (dgv[j, i].Value.ToString() == "")
                    {
                        style = dgv[j, i].Style;
                        style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        dgv[j, i].Style = style;
                    }
```