# Custom Datagridviewcolumn background color when selected

Tags: c#, datagridviewcolumn

I have created a custom DataGridviewColumn inherited from DataGridViewColumn. I am painting an Icon based on the underlying data being true or false. I can't work out how to establish if the underlying row is seleted so that I can paint the cell background accordingly. I unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
if (cellState == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(cellStyle.SelectionBackColor), cellBounds);
                }
                else
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor), cellBounds);
                }
```

The only other option would be to reference the parent grid and check the selected status based on the *rowIndex*. Is there a better way, and how do I reference the parent grid?

Comment: have u tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview

Comment: I've created a custom column and I want to be able to paint the background color from within the paint event when drawing the cell. I don't want to have to deal with row colors etc every time I use the custom column.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. The DataGridViewCell exposes the parent grid which can be checked for the selected row.

```
if (this.DataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Selected)
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(cellStyle.SelectionBackColor), cellBounds);
                }
                else
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor), cellBounds);
                }
```