# C# DatagridView row color based on Color saved on another table with mySQL

Tags: c#, colors, row

I am using C# and mySQL for backend database.
I have 2 tables. One with order statuses (Status table) with columns ID, Name, Color

```
ID Status    Color
1,New order, Blue
2,Completed, Green
```

I also have another tables with orders(Order tables) with columns OrderID, Status, Price

```
OrderID  Status     Price
1        New Order  150
```

When I search for the orders I fill the datagridview.

What is the best way to color the rows of the datagridview based on the values of the status color in status table?

Answer (score 0):

You can look here: [How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

Load your values in the grid and set the Backcolor of your rows depending on your value.

Comment: This article is about how to color a datagridview based on cell value. I want a kind of different code. I want to color the rows in datagrid view based on a value on another table(status).

Comment: For example when someone changes the status color in the status table to be applied also on datagridview. The status names and colors are not standard so the user may change the name and the color code. I want when the status maches the status on status table the color be changed accordingly