# Changing datagridview row color based on condition

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cell

I have loaded the data from database to `DatagridView` and have some Reservations of cars with Start and End date . So loading data is not a problem. `StartDate` and `Shortdate` in my database are shortdatabase I mean only dates without time.
I do like following to load them and I want those row who the same as today or older than today I want to have colored RED. I mean `ForeColore = red`. How can I do that?

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
var shortDate = today.Date.AddDays(0);

var ReservedCars = (from r in db.Reservation 
                    select new
                    {
                      ReservationID = r.ReservationId,
                      Startdate = r.StartDate,
                      Enddate = r.EndDate 
                    }).ToList();


            dgvReservedRooms.DataSource = ReservedCars; 
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            var shortDate = today.Date.AddDays(0);

// I tried like this but doesn't work with colors, please help...
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvReservedCars.Rows)
            { 
                foreach (var re in ReservedCars)
                {
                    if (re.Enddate <= shortDate)
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure it enters the if to change the row color? Or that's your problem?

Comment: Handle `CellFormatting` and set style of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple likely issues.  First: your for statement that is doing the coloring checks.  For each row in the datagridview it's going through every reservation (not just the reservation associated with that row), and if any of them have an Enddate <= today then that row gets set to red.  So if any reservations have an Enddate <= today then all of them will get colored red.  Instead you need to check if the reservation associated with that row has an Enddate <= today.

Second, you need to put your row styling changes in the `DataBindingComplete` event for the `DataGridView`, not in the same function that sets up the datasource.  I believe you're running into the same issue that was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13560694/2263392

So with both of these changes the code looks something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    var shortDate = today.Date.AddDays(0);

    var ReservedCars = (from r in db.Reservation 
        select new ReservationRow(
            r.ReservationId,
            r.StartDate,
            r.EndDate)).ToList();

    dgvReservedCars.DataSource = ReservedCars;
}

private void dgvReservedCars_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    var shortDate = today.Date.AddDays(0);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvReservedCars.Rows)
    {
        ReservationRow res = row.DataBoundItem as ReservationRow;
        if (res.EndDate <= shortDate)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `ReservationRow` is simply:

```
public class ReservationRow
{
    public int ReservationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public ReservationRow(int id, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        ReservationId = id;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , but res.EndDate <= shortDate this res.EndDate must come from Reservation table. Otherwise how can we compair? Your solutions givs me null at res.EndDate.

Comment: `row.DataBoundItem` will be the `ReservationRow` that is associated with that dgv row.  Are you using my `ReservationRow` class? I replaced your select new using anonymous types with `ReservationRow` to allow accessing the `row.DataBoundItem` here.