# Change row color DataGridView C #

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with a Column called `accepted`, its value can be `True` or `False` as it has been modified.

I want to change the row color to green if is `True` or red otherwise. In the database the data type is `Bit`

This is what I have.

But when you start the application, the color does not change

```
private void dataReporte_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataReporte.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "accepted")
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value) == true)
        {
            dataReporte.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        }
        else
        {
            dataReporte.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `dataReporte.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;`. Be careful to filter unwanted indexes (`-1` and the `new` Row).

Comment: What happens when you use the debugger?  Put a debug stop on that first line and watch what happens when you run it.  CurrentRow and e.RowIndex may not be the same thing.

Comment: Don't use CurrentRow property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to change the current style, not the default one, try this

```
private void dataReporte_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.dataReporte.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "accepted")
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value) == true)
            {
                dataReporte.CurrentRow.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
            }
            else
            {
                dataReporte.CurrentRow.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

            }
```