# Problem with coloring Row in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I want the user to be able to select a whole row in the datagrid and then click a button to change the color to one he selected in combobox.

The problem is The Color isn't changing.

All Console.WriteLines are appearing in the console

This is my code:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("11");
                if (comboBox_Color.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("12");
                    DataGridViewRow r = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
                    switch (comboBox_Color.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    {
                        case "Rot":
                            if (r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red) return;
                            Console.WriteLine("13");
                            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            updateColor(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), "Rot");//<= Writes the color into the Local DB
                            break;
                        case "Grün":
                            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                            updateColor(r.Cells[0].ToString(), "Grün");
                            break;
                        case "Gelb":
                            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            updateColor(r.Cells[0].ToString(), "Gelb");
                            break;
                        case "Blau":
                            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                            updateColor(r.Cells[0].ToString(), "Blau");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You didn't mention what you have set the DGV's `SelectionMode` to.

Comment: RowHeaderSelect

Comment: ...and are you actually clicking on the Row header, before calling, e.g.,  `r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;`? I.e., is the Row fully selected? Have you tried setting FullRowSelect instead? I.e.2, have you debugged this code, verifying that one of the switch cases is hit?

Comment: yes the row is fully selected otherwise I wouldn't get all logs. FullRowSelected doesn't works either.

Comment: could the row already be painted? check out this thread, it's old, but might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview

Comment: Well, when you set the `Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`, the Row Color changes. If it doesn't, something is preventing it from changing, the Control is not the one you're looking at, you didn't move the Row selection to a different one (until you do, you'll see the row colored in the HighLigth color), your DGV is repainting the Row to a default color (e.g., custom alternating colors), etc. Debug your code: put a breakpoint in one of the `case`, select that Color and proceed step by step, to see whether something gets in the way. Give some context to this code: where are you calling it from?

Comment: When going through the code line by line there is still nothing happening(the color is not changing but the lines are executed).
The code is called by a button press (so the form is fully loaded)

Comment: Step by step debugging is not meant to *make something happen*, is meant to see what code is executed and what this code is doing. What happens in `updateColor()`? Are you resetting the DataSource? Something else? Have you tried to change the Row Color after you've called `updateColor()`?

Comment: Jap I reseted the DataSource. *FacePalm*. Now it works, thanks for the help.