# Color the rows and column in c# datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, windows-forms-designer, excel-reader

I'm, trying to color the rows and columns after importing the excel sheet into datagridview.

1. Rows (A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6) should be highlighted in red. (maximum row count is 35)
2. Columns (Fields, Record 1, Record 2, Record 3, Record 4, Record 5, Record 6, Record 7) should be highlighted in orange. (columns count is not fixed, will be different each time).

   ```
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
   dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
   ```

But above code color the unwanted area. How to resolve this.

(colored area in the attached picture should be in white and arrow pointed area should consider the colorings.)

[image]

Comment: You're changing the color of the row and column _headers_. Of course that won't change the color of the _rows_ and _columns_ themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

Comment: @h3r, is any update?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to set the first row's color and the first column's color.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default row color and alternate row color styles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-alternating-row-styles-for-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

```
this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
this.dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor =
    Color.Beige;
```