# DataGridview row color change based on the job role using C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple application in C#. I can add the records. I can view the records in a DataGridview successfully. But I am stuck with color change of row.

The color needs to change based on the employee role for easy  identification. Employee has one of 3 roles: sales manager, software engineer, project manager.

Software engineer employee's color needs to be shown as red, project managers in blue, sales manager in yellow.

This is what I tried so far - error displayed as invalid attempt

```
private DataTable GetDataFromDB()
            {
        
               
            }

            private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "role")
                {
                    ColorRow(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
                }
            }


        private void ColorAllRows() 
    {
              foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
                ColorRow(row);
              }
    }

        private void ColorRow(DataGridViewRow row)
        {
            if (row.Cells["role"].Value != null)
            {
                switch (row.Cells["role"].Value.ToString())
                {
                    case "a":
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        return;
                    case "b":
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
                        return;
                    case "c":
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                        return;
                }
            }
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

}
`read[2]` is the role - how use if condition and change the color of the grid cell based on the role?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

Comment: i went this article before i posted didn't solve it.i updated the question above

Comment: can you write the code for this

Comment: `int x = dataGridView1.Rows.Add...` then `dataGridView1.Rows[x].DefaultCellStyle...` ?

Comment: int x = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows.Add(read[2]).ToString());  dataGridView1.Rows[x].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;   still error man error displayed as invalid attempt there is no data present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to avoid “manually” adding the rows to the grid as your code shows… `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(read[0],read[1],read[2],read[3]);` … Read the data from the query into a `DataTable`, then use that table as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridView`. Manually adding the rows is only going to create “more” work for you.

In reference to changing the row color based on the value in the “Role” cell, you can use the grids `CellValidating` event or the grids `CellValueChanged` event. The `CellValidating` event may fire more times than we need so that is the reason I prefer using the grids `CellValueChanged` event as shown below. This event will fire when the user changes a cells value and tries to leave the cell. Unfortunately, this event is NOT triggered when the grids `DataSource` is set. Therefore, we will need to implement a method that loops through the rows in the grid and color the rows “after” the grid has it’s `DataSource` set.

Because of this it may simplify things if we make a simple method that takes a `DataGridViewRow` row and checks the “Role” cells value and then colors the row accordingly. We should then be able to use that method in the `CellValueChanged` event AND the method we need to color the rows after the data is loaded into the grid. This straight-forward `ColorRow` method may look something like…

```
private void ColorRow(DataGridViewRow row) {
  if (row.Cells["Role"].Value != null) {
    switch (row.Cells["Role"].Value.ToString()) {
      case "Sales Manager":
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        return;
      case "Software Engineer":
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
        return;
      case "Project Manager":
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        return;
    }
  }
  row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

If the given row’s “Role” cell is `null` or is not one of the targeted role types, then the row is colored White. Otherwise the row is colored according to the “role” cells value.

This should simplify both the `CellValueChanged` event code and the method we need to loop through the rows and color depending on the “Role” cells value. The event and method may look something like…

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Role") {
    ColorRow(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
  }
}

private void ColorAllRows() {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    ColorRow(row);
  }
}
```

To test this, below is a small, yet complete, example demonstrating what is described above.

```
DataTable GridDT;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridDT = GetDataFromDB();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridDT;
  ColorAllRows();
}

private DataTable GetDataFromDB() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Role", typeof(string));
  Random rand = new Random();
  string curRole = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    switch (rand.Next(3)) {
      case 1:
        curRole = "Software Engineer";
        break;
      case 2:
        curRole = "Project Manager";
        break;
      default:
        curRole = "Sales Manager";
        break;
    }
    dt.Rows.Add("Name " + i, curRole);
  }
  return dt;
}
```

The code should produce something like…

[image]

Comment: i modified the code above how to retrieve the data from the database still couldn't solve the problem

Comment: … ? … in the updated code… “why” are you using “my code” that simply creates some “test” data… ? … It appears the code is getting the “real” data with… `ada1.Fill(dt);` … ? … Where is the `CellValueChanged` event… ? … Where is the `ColorRow` method and where are you calling it?

Comment: CellValueChanged ColorRow  i added sir. still i getting the error of   dt.Rows.Add(curRole);

Comment: I see your changes, however and for a second time... "WHY" did you add my code that adds random test data... ? ... this may work however, I am confident you will get an error. The code "already" has the data with ... `ada1.Fill(dt);` ... use THAT `dt` and remove the code that adds the random values to the table.

Comment: now data displyed color not changed

Comment: i updated above

Comment: Where is the forms `Load` event? You would want to call the `ColorAllRows();` method in the forms load event and AFTER the grids `DataSource` has been set.

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ColorAllRows();
            GetDataFromDB();
        }          i already called but color was not changed

Comment: The reason there are no colored rows, is because the code is calling `ColorAllRows();` BEFORE the grid gets the data... `GetDataFromDB`... so there would be no rows in the grid when `ColorAllRows()` is called. Please look a little closer at my code and note that `ColorAllRows()` is called AFTER the call to get data AND setting the grids `DataSource`.

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        
            GetDataFromDB();
            ColorAllRows();
        }             still white only shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240568/discussion-between-johng-and-creative-one2018).

Comment: To help expedite this, you may want to join the chat.