# C# datagridview alternating background color based on matching records

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I have an unbound datagridview on a windows form that has alternating background colored rows based on matching fields(L_NAME, F_NAME, DOB, ETC...). However the background color for some fields aren't colored.

An example of what needs to happen:

- default background color is white
- colors show matched records (gray and purple)
  [image: Ex of whats intended]

Example of whats happening:

- certain fields are default background colored, white
- some fields within a row are the default color of the datagridview (which isn't supposed to happen)
  [image: Ex of whats happening]

There are methods that are validating the fields that are using the default background color, so I'm sure its re-coloring the background but I need to change the background back to its assigned color. I tried changing the background color using RowPrePaint, RowPostPaint, and Paint. I also tried changing the colors of each row at the end of the method that validates those values but the default background color remains unchanged.

So when should I color the Row background to keep its assigned color?

Comment: Are you actually changing the color on the Row? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview - asking because its rather impossible if individual cells wouldn’t have the correct background if you did

Comment: Post your code -- If you need to define the Cells' color, not the Rows', use the CellFormatting / CellPainting events. Otherwise, the events you have mentioned will do